# Execute a synchronous command asynchronously in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, asynchronous, xamarin.forms

I've built a Xamarin.Forms app that is using a DLL from a tierce app to send kind of SQL command (this is not SQL !)

Probleme is that it only provides synchronous methods and my app is then "not responding". How can I do an asynchronous method that will call the sycnhronous one and wait for its result without hanging the UI ?

I tried the following but it seems to be waitng forever like if thread was never stopping.

```
public async Task<ExecuteCommandResult> ExecuteMocaCommandAsync(String ps_command)
    {
        return await Task<ExecuteCommandResult>.Run(() =>
            {
                return ExecuteMocaCommand(ps_command);
            }
        );
    }
```

and I'm calling it like this :

```
ExecuteCommandResult l_res = l_con.ExecuteMocaCommandAsync("list users where usr_id = '" + gs_UserName + "'").Result;
```

I'm clearly missing something and hope you can point me in the good direction.

Regards,
Yoz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Task.Run` looks good (though you can simplify it by changing `Task<ExecuteCommandResult>.Run` to just `Task.Run`). That's the proper way to push blocking work to a background thread in a UI application.

However, you can't use `Result`; [that can deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). You'll need to call your method using `await`:

```
ExecuteCommandResult l_res = await l_con.ExecuteMocaCommandAsync("list users where usr_id = '" + gs_UserName + "'");
```

Comment: Thank you very much that was the trick ! I knew it was a stupid and easy thing. For others having this issue, also note that the method calling the async method must also be tagued async if using await !